# Generating Sub-Arrays of Overlapping Ranges

Tags: c#, overlap, range

my name is Timothy Sassone.  I am working on developing some scheduling software of a sort in C#, but have run into some trouble.  This last part of the program is intended to take a large list of weekly events (stored as day(s) of the week and a start and end time), and sort them into sub-lists containing events that overlap with one-another (such that no one could possibly have attended two of the events in the sublist).

At the moment, it does this by finding the "longest" event in the list ((endTime-startTime)*numDays), and adding it and every course it overlaps with to a sub-list.  It then finds all the "conflicts" (events which do not overlap) and resolves them while removing the fewest number of courses possible.  This much I have, but with the number of ranges I have to deal with, I end up with a rather high number of sub-lists.  Is there any better way to split the list, such that I end up with fewer sub-lists?

I have considered a brute-force method, simply trying every possibility and going with the best, but the number of ranges is high enough (anywhere from 100-500 on average) that doing so could be rather slow.  Any suggestions or pointers would be most appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Timothy Sassone

Comment: I don't think I get it. If event1 overlaps with event2 and event2 overlaps with event3, should they all go in the same sublist even though event1 might not overlap with event3?

Comment: No.  The goal is to have the lists formed such that no one could possibly attend two of the events from any given list.  If event1 overlapped with event2 and event3, but event2 and event3 didn't overlap, they could attend both event2 and event3.  I will be scheduling other events based on these lists, and the time for the new events can only afford to overlap (thus preventing anyone from attending both) if the two weekly events involved also overlap.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Time Period Library for .NET** http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx includes the **TimePeriodIntersector** to search for overlapping time periods.

The overlaps are calculated with a linear and fast algorithm by counting/sorting all moments on the time line.

And the usage of **TimePeriodIntersector** looks like:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void TimePeriodCombinerSample()
{
  TimePeriodCollection periods = new TimePeriodCollection();

  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 01 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 10 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 04 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 08 ) ) );

  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 15 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 18 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 18 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 22 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 20 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 24 ) ) );

  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 26 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 30 ) ) );

  TimePeriodCombiner<TimeRange> periodCombiner = new TimePeriodCombiner<TimeRange>();
  ITimePeriodCollection combinedPeriods = periodCombiner.CombinePeriods( periods );

  foreach ( ITimePeriod combinedPeriod in combinedPeriods )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Combined Period: " + combinedPeriod );
  }
  // > Combined Period: 01.03.2011 - 10.03.2011 | 9.00:00
  // > Combined Period: 15.03.2011 - 24.03.2011 | 9.00:00
  // > Combined Period: 26.03.2011 - 30.03.2011 | 4.00:00
} // TimePeriodCombinerSample
```